# I want to prevent clicks but allow dragging on dropping on jQuery elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a list of buttons aligned horizontally in a rectangular box. Each button's position is calculated based on previous buttons width.

All these are draggables and the box is a droppable. I am able to drag and drop them and also re arrange them in desired order, but if I click on a button rapidly, its causing other buttons to calculate their position wrong and they are getting scattered.

I can prevent this just by disabling these rapid clicks, but I have no idea how to prevent them.

Is there a way, where we can prevent such rapid clicks on draggables ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to delay clicks? or DnD itself? Please add more details or share an [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You could something like this?

```
var stopClick = false;
var interval;
var stopForTime = 200; //200 ms
$('.draggable').click(function(e){
    if (stopClick) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    stopClick = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
        stopClick = false;
    }, stopForTime);
});
```

Comment: no luck, its same even after disabling clicks for some time

Comment: Ok, I probably can't help unless you can post code examples of what you're doing and what you've tried.